# How can I get the new height of a wrapedtext of DrawText();?

Tags: delphi, word-wrap, drawtext

code sample

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  r: Trect;
  s: String;
begin
  R := Rect(0,0, 300, 100);
  s := 'WordWrapTextOut(TargetCanvas: TCanvas; var x, y: integer; S: string; maxwidth, lineheight: integer);';
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(s),  length(s), R, DT_WORDBREAK or DT_LEFT);
end;
```

I want to wrap the text in 300px width but how can I get the new Height? Is there a way or any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update your rectangle before drawing the text you could use DT_CALCRECT. DrawText will then modify your rectangle to the new height (and width if necessary). If you only need the height though use the return value as Andreas Rejbrand showed.

Here's a sample of this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  r: Trect;
  s: String;
begin
  R := Rect(0,0, 300, 100);
  s := 'WordWrapTextOut(TargetCanvas: TCanvas; var x, y: integer; S: string; maxwidth, lineheight: integer);';
  if DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(s),  length(s), R, DT_CALCRECT or DT_WORDBREAK or DT_LEFT) <> 0 then
  begin
    DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(s),  length(s), R, DT_WORDBREAK or DT_LEFT);
    r.Top := r.Bottom;
    r.Bottom := r.Bottom * 2;
    DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(s),  length(s), R, DT_WORDBREAK or DT_LEFT);
  end;
end;
```

I would recommend reading the docs for more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4):

The height of the drawn text is the returned value of [`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498%28VS.85%29.aspx).

```
HeightOfText := DrawText(...
```

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438876/how-can-i-get-the-new-height-of-a-wrapedtext-of-drawtext/6443798#6443798) you can get it by calling [DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with `DT_CALCRECT` flag specified what actually won't paint anything; it just calculates appropriate rectangle and returns it to variable `R`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
  S: String;
begin
  R := Rect(0, 0, 20, 20);
  S := 'What might be the new high of this text ?';
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(S), Length(S), R, DT_WORDBREAK or DT_LEFT or DT_CALCRECT);
  ShowMessage('New height might be '+IntToStr(R.Bottom - R.Top)+' px');
end;
```

What means if you call it twice using the following example, you'll get drawn the wrapped text. It's because the first call with `DT_CALCRECT` calculates the rectangle (and modify `R` variable by doing it) and the second call draws the text in that modified rectangle area.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
  S: String;
begin
  R := Rect(0, 0, 20, 20);
  S := 'Some text which will be stoutly wrapped and painted :)';
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(S), Length(S), R, DT_WORDBREAK or DT_LEFT or DT_CALCRECT);
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(S), Length(S), R, DT_WORDBREAK or DT_LEFT);
end;
```